# Why does the C7 chord contain a flattened 7th instead of the real 7th note?

Tags: chords, notation

I have already check this out (Why does the dominant chord contain a flattened 7th?).

I'm not interested in (more or less) dissonant chords, neither in construction of the dominant chords.

My point is: the 7th note (of the C major scale) is B (not B flat) 
*** [C, D, E, F, G, A, B] ***

It must be a convention.

That said, does anyone know why (and, if possible, WHEN) this convention was adopted using the "7th flattened" instead of *THE REAL 7th* note of the scale to form what today we know as C7 (or anything 7)?